# One Entity Linked to Multiple Entities EF Core 5 Code-First

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have an entity which is a general purpose table storing multiple types of data such as Item Types, Trader Types etc.

[General Entity Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSDG8.png)

Now I have to make relationship with this entity with multiple entities such as Items, Traders etc and each entity may have multiple references to this general entity in a single object (item/row)

Usually in DB-First approach I would create the Foreign Keys in each table referring to the General table.

But here when I add the foreign keys and select data, the referred property would return as null even though the foreign key column has a value. It even checks the constraints when adding a new row.

[The entity which contains the Foreign Keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRbCd.png)

[Querying data in controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDG0s.png)

Now I am not sure if I am doing something wrong in Entity relationships or when querying/selecting the data. Please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: Is this like an enum table?

Comment: Yes you could say that, works like an enum table

Comment: Could you insert your code as text in the question

Comment: In general, look at [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/) documentation topic. `virtual` is not enough to achieve lazy loading if that was the intent. The standard way is to use eager loading, i.e. adding `Include` statements in the query for the members you want loaded along with the main entity.